# If activecell interior color changes then

Tags: excel, vba

I want the following VBA code:

If the activecell interior color changes to colorindex 44 then I want the cell five columns to the right to have the text "Done" and today's date.

I have tried the below but only works when I move the selected cell to the right. It also does not stop working when a cell color is NOT changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange  (ByVal Target As Range)

   If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = "Done" & Date
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no event that is triggered by the changing of a cell colour, unless that colour is triggered by conditional formatting in which case the Change/Calculate events may come into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `Target` instead of `ActiveCell`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=4).Value = "Done " & Date
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this cannot check if the color was changed or not as there is no event for that. You can only test if the actual color index is 44. But to prevent overwriting the "change" date you can just test if the date already exists.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count + Target.Columns.Count > 2 Then Exit Sub 'exit if more than one cell is selected

    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 And Not Left$(Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=4).Value, 4) = "Done" Then
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=4).Value = "Done " & Date
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peh I have modified your code to the below and seems to work well:

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal     Target As Range)
        If Target.Rows.Count + Target.Columns.Count     > 2 Then Exit Sub 'exit if     more than one cell is selected
        If Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44     And Not Left$(Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value, 4) = "Done" Then
        
        y = MsgBox("Override?", vbYesNo)
        
        If y = vbYes Then
        
            Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value = "Done " & Date
        
        End If
    End If
End Sub